# Graphite movingAverage for only existing datapoints

Tags: graphite

Let's say I have the following metric:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FkDp.png

I want to calculate the moving average for last reported 5 values. 
Unfortunately, the movingAverage(series,5) function is taking into account the Null, or None values, and not producing movingAverage for the visible data:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTZ2S.png

I want to see the moving average for ONLY the X last existing (that is, visible) data points (therefore, not Null, or None -- on the graph above, those would be the visible 100's and 0's).

Can this be achieved in Graphite? If so, what function could be used?